# Is there a way to get the text below Application Bar Icons to show all the time?

Tags: windows-phone-7, application-bar

I am pretty new to the windows phone.

Is there a way to get the text at the bottom of the icon in the application bar to show all the time as apposed to when the ellipses are clicked??

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid the answer is no.

This is the way the OS was designed and even if it was possible you should not really be trying to make your app break the design guidelines.